# Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка прокрутки наверх появлялась только тогда, когда выполняются определенные условия (описал условия ниже)

Tags: javascript, анимация

Условия появления 'кнопки наверх':

1. когда прокручена определенная часть контента  - реализовал
2. когда юзер прокрутил страницу наверх относительно текущего положения позиции скроллa

1-е условие реализовано, осталось добавить второе.

Код:

```
var scrollToTopBtn = document.querySelector(".scrollToTopBtn");
var rootElement = document.documentElement;   //document.documentElement возвращает корневой элемент документа, нужен нам для получения значений смещения

function handleScroll() {                     // handleScroll будет вызываться каждый раз, когда пользователь прокручивает страницу, теперь нужно общее количество пикселей, которые  можно прокрутить
  
  var scrollTotal = rootElement.scrollHeight - rootElement.clientHeight;  // scrollHeight дает высоту элемента, включая ту часть, которая не видна из-за переполнения, clientHeight дает внутреннюю высоту элемента в пикселях, которая является высотой видимой части                                                         
                                                                          //Если вычитать из scrollHeight clientHeight, получим общее количество пикселей, которые можно прокрутить

  if ((rootElement.scrollTop / scrollTotal > 0.76)) {                      //scrollTotal  представляет собой максимальное количество пикселей, которые можно прокручивать по вертикали
                                                                           //разделив количество прокручиваемых пикселей на общее количество пикселей, которые  можно прокрутить, получим соотношение от 0 до 1
    scrollToTopBtn.classList.add("showBtn");
  } else {
    
    scrollToTopBtn.classList.remove("showBtn");
  }
}

function scrollToTop() {
  
  rootElement.scrollTo({
    top: 0,                                            //прокуртка к макс.верхней точки экрана
    behavior: "smooth"                                 // плавная прокрутка 
  });
}
scrollToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", scrollToTop); //прослушиватель событий клика
document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
```